# set the request header in xforms xforms:set-request-header

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I'm able get the request header value using the below code.

```
value="xxforms:get-request-header('user-id')"
```

I would like to set the value of `user-id` in the request header which is being used while saving the form.

Please suggest some solution on the same.

Comment: @Thangamani, you would like to set the `user-id` HTTP header and you want that header to go back to the browser? (I am asking as this sounds somewhat unusual to me.)

Comment: @Alex, Yes. I would like to set the user-id in the HTTP Request Header.

Comment: To save the form, are you using Form Runner, or just a plain XForms submission?

Comment: @Alex/Ebruchez, I would like to retain the Single sign-on information for submitting the form which was initially set while rendering the form

Comment: @Thangamani, got it. I think the bottom line is that you need to implement that function since it isn't available. I put more information about this in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, there is no `xxforms:set-request-header()` function at this point, but it wouldn't be hard to implement, and you're lucky, since Orbeon Forms happens to be open source ;). See the [implementation of `xxforms:get-request-header()`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/function/xxforms/XXFormsGetRequestHeader.java), and you should be able to create a corresponding `xxforms:set-request-header()`. The [code](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms) is in GitHub, and you'll find an Ant `build.xml` at the root.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the xforms:header to post the information with the request:

```
<xforms:submmission>
    <xforms:header>
        <xforms:name>userid</xforms:name>
        <xforms:value>...</xforms:value>
    </xforms:header>
</xforms:submmission>
```

At least this works with "static" values, I haven't yet figured out how to use the value from get-request-header as the value of the submitted header.